# Why does the getConnection method needs to be synchronized in ConnectionPool class?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am writing a ObjectPool class for pooling of an Object instance. While looking at the existing codes on internet I saw that the getConnection method is synchronized. I am confused.Why do we require the getConnection method to be synchronized?
Here is the code sample.

```
 public synchronized Connection getConnection() {
        Connection con = null;
        if (freeConnections.size() > 0) {
            // Pick the first Connection in the Vector
            // to get round-robin usage
            con = (Connection) freeConnections.firstElement();
            freeConnections.removeElementAt(0);
            try {
                if (con.isClosed()) {
                    log("Removed bad connection from " + name);
                    // Try again recursively
                    con = getConnection();
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                log("Removed bad connection from " + name);
                // Try again recursively
                con = getConnection();
            }
        }
        else if (maxConn == 0 || checkedOut < maxConn) {
            con = newConnection();
        }
        if (con != null) {
            checkedOut++;
        }
        return con;
    }
```

I mean per thread we will be creating a new instance of the ConnectionManager which will fetch a connection from the ConnectionPool. Why do we require a synchronized method in the ConnectionPool class? Please explain. I am very confused.

Comment: Well, suppose it weren't synchronized... how would you achieve the thread safety required where if there's one connection available and two threads both call `getConnection` at the same time, it behaves correctly?

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (freeConnections.size() > 0) {                      // A
        // Pick the first Connection in the Vector
        // to get round-robin usage
        con = (Connection) freeConnections.firstElement(); // B
        freeConnections.removeElementAt(0);                // C
```

Imagine if two threads run this code in the following order: A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2. They will each get the same connection to process (the one that is first), and then the second thread will remove a second connection that neither of them has taken (the second one)!

Answer (score 1):

Since getConnection method is designed to be called concurrently with a single DataSource instance.So It ensures thread safety of your DataSource.Moreover JDBC doesnt provide thread safety as such.

By thread safety we mean that a resource is allocated to a single thread at a particular time and nobody can access it while it's used by that thread.This behavior prevents dirty read/write.However syncrhronization can be generalized  at class level and doesnt need to be local.Also if getConnection is used within a constructor/initializer method it may be called where ever needed in the program provided it is closed properly each time.In this case you wont need explicit serialization.

Answer (score 0):

So there is a need to synchronize the action of multiple threads and make sure that only one thread can access the resource at a given point in time.

Answer (score 0):

There are different strategies to make a connection to a database from JAVA. Mainly for thread safety you need to make your getConnection Synchronized in your ConnectionPool class. If you have more than one thread in your program, there may be a possibility that more than one thread may call your getConnection at the same time. In that case it would not ensure thread safety unless you make it synchronized.

Once you use synchronized keyword, it ensures that a single thread will access your getConnection making it a thread safe affair.

Though it is not explicitly mentioned in java docs, DataSource#getConnection method is designed to be called concurrently on a single DataSource instance.